# Camera is not working for scanning

Tags: android, zbar

```
implementation  of main class:    
    
public class Main Activity extends Activity implements ZBarScannerView.ResultHandler {
          
    private ZBarScannerView mscannerview ;
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
    }

    public void onClick1(View view){
                
        mscannerview=new ZBarScannerView(this);                    
        setContentView(mscannerview);                    
        mscannerview.setResultHandler(this);
        mscannerview.startCamera();                

    }
        
    @Override public void onPause() {
                
        super.onPause();
        mscannerview.stopCamera();
        
     }
        
     @Override public void handleResult(Result result) {
                
         Log.w("handleResult", result.getContents());
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         builder.setTitle("Scan result");
         builder.setMessage(result.getContents());
         AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
         alertDialog.show();
            
    }
}
```

Error :2-18 01:42:51.809  14705-14851/com.anewapplication W/CameraBase﹕ An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0

Its a simple implementation of Zbar library and my camera is not popping out for scanning ! Help me out ! Thanks in advance.

## beginner in android.

Comment: post the error log..

Comment: where are you registering for the click event ? can you please share the complete Activity class code and the error log ?

Comment: try removing the line 'setContentView(mScannerView)'. what is this line for? Error Log?

Comment: Process: com.project.saxena.akshay.attendance_mgmt_system,    PID: 12654
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method Registeractivity(View) in the activity class com.project.saxena.akshay.attendance_mgmt_system.Login_activity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4012)

Comment: error is in Login_activ‌​ity class

Comment: Can you update your post with the error message? It makes it easier for us to read when it is formatted in the post versus reading it when it is squeezed between comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting any `Button`s in this code to be clicked. So if you are setting the `OnClickListener` directly from your `xml` `layout` then you should pass the view as parameter to the method that will handle its click event which i do not see on your method (you do not have any parameters).

You can do like so :

```
public void onClick1(View v){
    mscannerview=new ZBarScannerView(this);
    setContentView(mscannerview);
    mscannerview.setResultHandler(this);
    mscannerview.startCamera();
}
```

and in your layout :

```
<Button android:onClick="onClick1"..... />
```

Comment: Thanks ! it worked . But my camera is still not working ..
2-18 01:42:51.809  14705-14851/com.project.saxena.akshay.anewapplication W/CameraBase﹕ An error occurred while connecting to camera: 0

Comment: Glad to hear that :)  please mark my answer as accepted. For the camera, you need to provide more code to figure out the problem.